# How to Secure an AWS Rest service

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

I'm Looking for a simple Java example for a Secured ASW Rest service using aws sigv4, say for 'user01'

What needs to 'wrap' the following?

```
        @RequestMapping(value = "/employee/{name}", method = RequestMethod.POST)
            public Employee getEmployee(@PathVariable("name") String name) {
            return  new Employee(name);
        }
```

What would the client look like. i.e. What needs to 'wrap' the following?

```
    Employee emp = restTemplate.postForObject(url, request, Employee.class);
```

I't only the AWS components that have thrown me, 
I believe its only takes a few lines of code from the EC2 SDK - but which lines?
The AWS documentation leads you all over the place but has few hard examples.

Comment: I've come to the conclusion the answer is you cant at least not for the above - If you build a rest service & say deploy it with ElasticBeanstalk you are essentially on your own. However if you build it with JAX-RS, and wrap it with Jrestless, the deploy to AWS API + AWS Lambda, then

Comment: you can make use of the AWS IAM infrastructure to secure the operations. Its not exactly sigv4, but it looks as close as I'm going to get. Overall it feels like a big investment just to make use of the AWS security infrastructure - but I'm no expert.